# Git grep gives unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, grep

I've cloned the entire directory. Now I want to search for the file with the phrase fatal: 'RuntimeException'

But, I keep getting that error.

```
~/core$ git grep throw RuntimeException;
fatal: ambiguous argument 'RuntimeException': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Here, core is the directory in which I have cloned the files.

PS: I'm new to this, so please excuse me if I've done something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are used to separate parameters, so git is thinking you want to search in revision or path named `RuntimeException;`. If you want to search for a string containing spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes to enclose your search pattern if there are more than one word, e.g.

```
$ git grep "throw RuntimeException;"
```